# Where is the StackOverflow podcast #87?

Tags: discussion, podcast

I have #86 from 24/3/2010, but nothing more recent.

Is it just me or am I blind?

Perhaps the IE bug has hit: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forums/index.cfm?action=showthread&threadid=248801&forumid=1

Comment: `[status-complete]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here it is](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/podcast-87/)

Answer (score 9):

[Podcast #86](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/podcast-86/):

> Remember, podcast will be on hiatus for a bit while we retool it — [your suggestions are welcome in the interim](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/podcast-future/), see you in about a month!

Comment: OK, so your saying I'm deaf, not blind. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 6):

It will be ready in 6 to 8 weeks.

Answer (score 5):

I realize that the podcast is on hiatus, but it would be nice to get a more precise idea of when to expect the next one. It was been slated to return "about a month" after the [last one aired a month ago](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/podcast-86/), but so far there's been no word on when it will resume.

For those that can't wait, Jeff is the guest on the [latest episode of Hanselminutes](http://hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=229).

**update: [it's out now](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/shows/detail4458.html)!**

Comment: Do you know Duke Nukem?